# the golden ticket

Tags: idiom-meaning

It is a dialog.

A: We're a small sporting goods company, but we're hoping to expand our presence online.

B: That's the golden ticket for sure.
Do your customers currently access content about your company or products online?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want to know the meaning of "golden ticket," try googling "define golden ticket."

Comment: The question is filed under "idiom-meaning." From that, plus the subject head, it's pretty easy to glean that he wants to know what the idiom "golden ticket" means. At least that's how I interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

"Golden ticket" is a reference from the book "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory," the terrific 1964 children's novel by author Roald Dahl. After the release of the 1971 movie, the phrase entered the informal American vernacular.

In both the book and the movie, finding one of five (I think) golden tickets is the only way to enter the mysterious Willy Wonka's top-secret chocolate factory, filled with sumptuous candy delights.

So used 'correctly,' it means "a way into a desired place to be, that's usually difficult to enter." Here, I think the user just meant "a way into a desired place to be." But it's close enough.

Here is a [link to the clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6AicW3Xp9EM) and song "I've Got A Golden Ticket" from the movie:

And here is a [picture](http://media.liveauctiongroup.net/i/8577/9891669_1.jpg?v=8CE71411245DD00) of the golden ticket:

Comment: I get downgraded for answering your question? Do you mind explaining?

Comment: Hi, M.Z. I'd like to advise you to read the guidelines of our Help Center once more. This question is off-topic because the meaning of "Golden Ticket" could be easily and readily found on the internet. Please try not to answer any off-topic questions. All the comments above indicate that the question is not good.

Comment: OK, will do. I'm new here, and simply trying to be helpful.

Comment: Please don't forget that rewarding poor-quality questions like this one with an answer,  writing a comment-like answer and no-research/reference answer never helps the community. You will learn more as time goes by. Good luck. :-)

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it answers the question with reference and link. Please take a look at the edit by clicking on "edited X minutes ago" over my user name. You will be able to learn how to merge the internet address into a related word.

Comment: Cool...so a hyperlink! Yes, I want to do that. Thanks @Rathony!!

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to English Language and Usage.